# CSV file is not getting populated

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to populate Sample 2 file by extracting data from Sample 1 file. 
Following is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
data = pd.read_csv ('C:\\Users\\[Redacted]\\Documents\\Python\\[Redacted]_Sample_1.csv')
data.dropna(inplace = True) 
new = data["Overall Value"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True) 
data["ID"]= new[0]
data["IP"]= new[1]
data["Time"]= new[2]
data.drop(columns =["Overall Value"], inplace = True) 
new.to_csv(r'C:\\Users\\[Redacted]\\Documents\\Python\\[Redacted]_Sample_2.csv')
```

Comment: Seems like the `expand=True` argument in your split function makes the return of the function of type dataFrame. Try expand=False to get a list as a return.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to test it out using this

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not when you try to write the csv file.

The code you wrote and error you reported are different

```
data["ID"]= new[0]
```

vs

```
data["Cqtq"]= new[0]
```

but the problem is in that line. Check the data types and you will see why it fails.

Comment: Thank you Micric - you're spot on. The log / script is different because I modified the script to exclude the actual column names to avoid sharing any confidential data on this forum. I am going to test using the expand = false & taking a look at the date[]=new[] line